# Checking if a record can be deleted without attempting to delete it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following (generic) procedure that determines if a record can be deleted by following foreign keys recursively.  It has worked great for a several years, but now we have encountered a situation that highlights its poor performance.  It is very slow when there are many (e.g. 1000) dependent records (be gentle -- I'm not a SQL expert and we don't have a DBA).  In one instance, attempting to check if a record could be deleted took almost 6 minutes because of the sheer number of dependent records, which led to a timeout in the code that called it.  And of course, it gets worse if those dependents also have dependents (and so on), which they often do.

Now, before someone suggests that I should attempt to delete in a try block, catch the failure in a catch block, and then roll back... I re-wrote my procedure to do exactly that, and it WAS fast (like, REALLY fast: 1sec instead of 6min).  Unfortunately, because the procedure is called within the context of an ambient transaction, if the attempt to delete the record fails, SQL throws an exception, which makes the ambient transaction invalid, making it impossible to do anything else within that transaction.

What I am looking for here are ways to improve the existing procedure to make it much faster.  I know cursors are slow, but I don't **think** it can be rewritten using set-based operations (am I right?), and I have almost no knowledge of CTEs.  If CTEs would improve performance significantly, I'll need lots of help modifying the code to use them.  If not, what are my other options?

I realize that my procedure calls other functions/procedures which are not shown here, but I don't think their implementations are relevant to improving the algorithm.  If someone is willing to help me and those implementations become relevant, I will happily provide them.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CanDeleteRecord
    @tableName NVARCHAR(128),
    @identityValue INT,
    @fkName NVARCHAR(128) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF -- this prevents SqlMetal from complaining about a nested recursive call limit
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @fkName = NULL

    IF (@tableName IS NULL) RETURN 0

    --PRINT 'CanDeleteRecord ' + @TableName + ' ' + CAST(@identityValue AS NVARCHAR(10))

    DECLARE fkCursor CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR
    SELECT  f.name AS ForeignKeyName,
            OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS DependentTableName,
            COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS DependentColumnName,
            OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName,
            COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferencedColumnName,
            f.delete_referential_action_desc AS OnDeleteAction
    FROM    sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
    WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = @tableName
            AND (
                  f.delete_referential_action_desc = 'NO_ACTION' -- gets dependents that would prevent delete 
                  OR f.delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE' -- gets dependents that could have dependents that would prevent delete
                ) 
    ORDER BY    OnDeleteAction DESC,
            DependentTableName

    DECLARE @canDelete INT = 1
    DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @foreignKeyName NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @dependentTableName NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @dependentColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @referencedTableName NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @referencedColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @onDeleteAction NVARCHAR(128)

    OPEN fkCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM fkCursor INTO @foreignKeyName, @dependentTableName, @dependentColumnName, @referencedTableName,
        @referencedColumnName, @onDeleteAction
        
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF ( @onDeleteAction = 'NO_ACTION' )
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @countOUT = COUNT(' + @dependentColumnName + ') FROM '
                        + @dependentTableName + ' WHERE ' + @dependentColumnName + ' = '
                        + CAST(@identityValue AS NVARCHAR(10))
                    DECLARE @count INT
                    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@countOUT INT OUTPUT', @countOUT = @count OUTPUT
                    IF ( @count != 0 )
                        BEGIN
                            SET @canDelete = 0
                            SET @fkName = @foreignKeyName
                        END
                    IF ( @canDelete = 0 )
                        BREAK   
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @tableHasIdentity INT = dbo.TableHasIdentity(default, @dependentTableName)
                    --PRINT @dependentTableName + ' has identity = ' + CAST(@tableHasIdentity AS NVARCHAR(10))
                    IF ( @tableHasIdentity != 0 )
                        BEGIN
                            --PRINT 'Getting identity column for table ' + @dependentTableName + '...'
                            DECLARE @identityColumnName NVARCHAR(128) = NULL
                            EXEC dbo.GetTableIdentityColumnName @dependentTableName, @identityColumnName OUTPUT
                            --PRINT 'Identity column is: ' + @dependentTableName + '.' + @identityColumnName
                    
                            DECLARE @dependentTableCursor CURSOR
                            EXEC dbo.CreateTableCursor @dependentTableName, @identityColumnName, @dependentColumnName,
                                @identityValue, @dependentTableCursor OUTPUT
                        
                            --PRINT 'Fetching records from ' + @dependentTableName + '...'
                            DECLARE @dependentIdentityValue INT
                            FETCH NEXT FROM @dependentTableCursor INTO @dependentIdentityValue
                            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                                BEGIN
                                    --PRINT 'CanDeleteRecord ' + @dependentTableName + ' '
                                    --    + CAST(@dependentIdentityValue AS NVARCHAR(10))
                                    EXEC @canDelete = dbo.CanDeleteRecord @dependentTableName, @dependentIdentityValue,
                                        @fkName OUTPUT
                                    IF ( @canDelete = 0 )
                                        BREAK
                                    FETCH NEXT FROM @dependentTableCursor INTO @dependentIdentityValue
                                END
                            IF ( @canDelete = 0 )
                                BREAK
                        
                            CLOSE @dependentTableCursor
                            DEALLOCATE @dependentTableCursor
                        END
                END
            FETCH NEXT FROM fkCursor INTO @foreignKeyName, @dependentTableName, @dependentColumnName,
                @referencedTableName, @referencedColumnName, @onDeleteAction
        END
        
    CLOSE fkCursor
    DEALLOCATE fkCursor

    RETURN @canDelete
END
```

Environment: SQL Server 2019/2022, SQL Azure, C# application

Comment: Have you tried using a [save point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to allow you to rollback only the delete aspect of the transaction?

Comment: Are you running with `SET XACT_ABORT ON`? A FK violation shouldn't doom the transaction otherwise. e.g. See https://dbfiddle.uk/vvn3a2-Y

Comment: As the saying goes, if you have to ask, you can't afford it. Make your transaction work and just delete stuff. If you wanna go this way, I would probably rewrite your queries to do if exists... instead of count since counting requires full fetch of data while exists can bail out early

Comment: Dale K.  Yes, I did try a savepoint.  It was one of many different attempts.  I believe, IIRC, it was also thwarted by the exception, which invalidates the ambient transaction.

Comment: Martin Smith, yes I had `SET XACT_ABORT ON`.  From what I read, it appeared that I needed it.  Maybe it wasn't needed?  I can provide that version of the routine, if it has a chance of working with modifications.

Comment: siggerman, that might be worth a try.  Not sure how much benefit it will give me, but I'll try it.

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` can be useful but you should toggle it off before you do this, as by design it will roll back any transaction on error and you don't want that

Comment: Martin, why wouldn't I want that?  In this case, whether the record can be deleted or not, I want to roll back.  The whole purpose of the procedure is to determine IF the record can be deleted, not to delete it.

Comment: siggerman, thanks for the suggestion.  I modified the `NO_ACTION` branch and re-ran my test case.  The procedure executed in 5m 41s.  It's a little bit faster, but nowhere near fast enough.

Update: I re-tested the original version, and it runs in 5m 42s.  So the change didn't help at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Well if you want the transaction to be rolled back if the FK delete throws an error and this is the behaviour that you are already getting what is the question for? It seems you don't want the transaction to be rolled back really. Because you want it to still be open and do other stuff. If the delete fails the **statement** will be rolled back either way. Also you need to `@` people if you want them to be notified of replies

Comment: @MartinSmith , I see what you're getting at.  I am always rolling back anyway, so I don't need to abort the transaction.  This might just work with `SET XACT_ABORT OFF`.  I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: @MartinSmith, the question is about how to get a performant procedure.  I rewrote the procedure to attempt the delete, but with `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the OUTER (ambient) transaction became invalid if the delete failed (I didn't realize that would be the case), and I don't want that.  If turning off XACT_ABORT will solve the problem, I'll be very happy and grateful to your sharp eye!

Comment: SUCCESS!  I finally have something that works.

Here's the algorithm:

In a TRY block:
1) If there's an ambient transaction, create a savepoint; else start a new transaction
2) Attempt to delete the record
3) If delete is successful and we created a savepoint, roll back to the savepoint; else roll back the transaction

In the CATCH block (if the delete fails):
1) Get the name of the foreign key that prevented the delete
2) If we created a savepoint, roll back to the savepoint; else roll back the transaction

Woo Hoo!